# Java convert a serialized object to another object

Tags: java, object, serialization, casting

I have two java data objects `ObjectFloat` is for deseriealize incoming requests, and `ObjectInt` is for outgoing requests. I receive `ObjectFloat` from an HTTP call with `Float` attributes, deserialize it, and call `upgradeMembers()`. So before I send the object out I want to process each `m_member1` and `m_member1` attribute with `upgradeMembers()` and then send it out as a type `ObjectInt`.

Object float:

```
public class ObjectFloat {
    @SerializedName("member_number_1")
    protected Float m_member1;

    @SerializedName("member_number_2")
    protected Float m_member2;

    public void upgradeMembers() {
        m_member1 = m_member1 * 100
        m_member1 = m_member1 * 100
    }
}
```

Object integer:

```
public class ObjectInt {
    @SerializedName("member_number_1")
    protected Integer m_member1;

    @SerializedName("member_number_2")
    protected Integer m_member2;

}
```

How would I be able to covert `ObjectFloat` to `ObjectInt` before I send the object out? (I don't mind losing the decimals). I was thinking maybe I could call `m_gson.toJson(objectfloat)` and the serialize it back to with `fromJson` ObjectInt but when I send it out I would have to serialize it again with `toJson()` would that be overkill?

Comment: Why not simply write code?

Comment: A simple "copy" constructor for instance

Comment: You mean something like create new object of type ObjectInt like ObjectInt objectInt = new ObjectInt() and call `objectInt.setMember1(objectFloat.getMember1())`  and `objectInt.setMember2(objectFloat.getMemeber2())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a *constructor* that takes `ObjectFloat` as a parameter. This way you can create an instance of ObjectInt based on an instance of ObjectFloat:

```
public class ObjectInt {
    protected Integer m_member1;
    protected Integer m_member2;

    public ObjectInt() {
        // default constructor allows creating an instance without ObjectFloat
    }

    public ObjectInt(ObjectFloat objectFloat) {
        this.m_member1 = objectFloat.m_member1.intValue();
        this.m_member2 = objectFloat.m_member2.intValue();
    }
}
```

When you've added this constructor, you can "convert" an ObjectFloat into an ObjectInt with

```
ObjectInt objectInt = new ObjectInt(objectFloat)
```

Comment: I was just looking into the copy constructor too, thanks so much for being patient. This is probably the cleanest way to do it.